# Ubuntu 14.04 does not boot from USB

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, usb, liveusb

I have `emachines e732g`, `SSD` with `windows 7 64` and `HDD`, on which I want to install `Ubuntu 14.04`. I try to create liveusb with help `Universal-USB-Installer` and `unetbootin-windows-608`. But my `BIOS` does not load from USB. I see:

```
PXE-EGI-Media test failure,check cable
PXE-MOF-Exiting PXE ROM
```

After that, my `Windows` boot from `SSD`.

How to install `Ubuntu`?

Comment: what is the partition type on the drive, and does your bios provide a function key (often F12) that allows you to select the boot device from a list?

Comment: @FrankThomas, my bootable USB is FAT32. Yes, I have F12 function. Then I can choose windows 7 or network boot option.

Comment: is your BIOS set to allow boot from USB, and is USB Device in the boot order list anywhere?

Comment: @FrankThomas, thank you for help. I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I my bootable USB with help `rufus-1.4.12.exe` - https://rufus.akeo.ie/